# How to attach a rotary scroll listener to Android Wear numberPicker?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I have been working for a day at this and still can't figure it out. I am making an Android app for an Android Wear device and I can't figure out how to detect the rotary wheel on the device to get scroll events. I know that by default the rotary wheel gets assigned to ScrollViews and Listviews, etc. and I've got that to work, but I can't get it to work on a simple NumberPicker. As suggested by Google API's, I've used the OnGenericMotionListener and while it does not throw any errors, it still doesn't pick up anything.

I would like the NumberPicker to scroll with the rotary wheel. My code is as follows. Nothing in logcat to show any errors:

```
                MyActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.number_picker);
                NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
                numberPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
                numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);       
                numberPicker.setMinValue(0);   
                numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
                numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                    OnValueChangeListener() {
                    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
                        oldVal, int newVal) {

                    }          
                });
                numberPicker.setOnGenericMotionListener(new OnGenericMotionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "Received scroll event:" + event.getAction());
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:             

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

[Add custom rotary input scrolling](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/rotary-input#custom-scrolling):

> If your scrollable view doesn't natively support rotary input
>   scrolling, or if you want to do something other than scrolling in
>   response to rotary input events (zoom in/out, turn dials, etc.), you
>   can use the RotaryEncoder methods in the Wearable Support Library.
>
> The following code snippet shows how to use RotaryEncoder to add
>   custom scrolling in your app's view:
>
> ```
> myView.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
>     @Override
>     public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
>         if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL && RotaryEncoder.isFromRotaryEncoder(ev)) {
>             // Don't forget the negation here
>             float delta = -RotaryEncoder.getRotaryAxisValue(ev) * RotaryEncoder.getScaledScrollFactor(
>             getContext());
>
>             // Swap these axes if you want to do horizontal scrolling instead
>             scrollBy(0, Math.round(delta));
>
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         return false;
>     }
> });
> ```

Anyway you can check the full guide about rotary events in android
 wear.

Comment: That is basically the code I am already using (with the exception of using the float and scrollBy items). The issue is that the code isn't picking up the MotionEvents at all.

Comment: @steven alright. Kindley check if setting the permissions in the manifest enables this 'motion' events as stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242174/android-wear-activity-onkeydown-is-not-getting-called?noredirect=1#comment87532602_50242174).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation it's a little confusing but it's all there, pay attention to the next paragraph:

> - Rotary input events are only sent to the focused view. These events
>     do not bubble up the view hierarchy. If there is no focused view, or
>     if the focused view returns false from View.onGenericMotionEvent,
>     then (and only then) the event is sent to
>     Activity.onGenericMotionEvent.

Basically all you have to do is override [onGenericMotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onGenericMotionEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) on your [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL && RotaryEncoder.isFromRotaryEncoder(ev)) {
            // Don't forget the negation here
            float delta = -RotaryEncoder.getRotaryAxisValue(ev) * RotaryEncoder.getScaledScrollFactor(
            getContext());

            // Swap these axes if you want to do horizontal scrolling instead
            scrollBy(0, Math.round(delta));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And that's it your Activity will receive all the rotary input events.