# Wear OS onKeyDown not firing for Ticwatch E

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have a Ticwatch E connected using ADB and I'm viewing the logcat. There is only one button on this device but when I press it, my onKeyDown method does not fire. I've been reading the Android documentation on [Physical buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/physical-buttons), and have followed what they have specified. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keyCode=" + keyCode + "; keyEvent=" + event.toString());

    if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ShowTokenActivity.onKeyDown: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0");
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ShowTokenActivity.onKeyDown: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1");
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ShowTokenActivity.onKeyDown: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2");
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ShowTokenActivity.onKeyDown: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3");
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My stackoverflow searching uncovered this:

- [Android wear activity onKeyDown is not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242174/android-wear-activity-onkeydown-is-not-getting-called)

I also read [Use Key Events Directly](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/wrist-gestures#using_key_events) from the android developer site which has an example with similar code to what I have above. The only difference is that the Activity class is final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the first one, is not available on Wear OS 2. And the first two are not available for apps in Wear OS 3.  From the docs.

> Note: Wear OS 3.0 reserves two buttons for the OS, in contrast to Wear OS 2.0 which reserved only one. This reduces the number of buttons you can assign actions to.

Comment: But I'm not even getting the first debug statement.

Comment: Exactly, I don't think the first one/two physical buttons have events sent to your app.

Comment: Ok. I see what you're saying. How can I determine if the button was pressed causing my app to stop?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Maybe just be backgrounding of your app?

Comment: How can I detect that? Also, if I wanted to continue tracking heart rate or something like that, how would I accomplish that?